# Bash: Read UTC timestamp from a file and transform to Local Time for different Target Timezones

Tags: python, bash, date

I have UTC timestamps in a file generated from using bash `date` like the following:

```
'Sat Mar 15 01:30:01 UTC 2014'
'Sat Mar 15 01:30:16 UTC 2014'
'Sat Mar 15 02:00:01 UTC 2014'
'Sat Mar 15 02:00:12 UTC 2014'
```

I need to transform the timestamps to the local time of different regions. For e.g. convert first entry above to HongKong time, second to Singapore and so on. I can generate the offsets which can be added to get the local time. So my offsets look like the following:

```
2:00
-5:00
 .
 .
```

One possible approach may be to parse the date using `Python` and then add/subtract the offset.

However I'm wondering if I can preferably do this in `Bash` with `date`. I've tried to increment/decrement the date such as:

```
date -d 'Sat Mar 15 01:30:01 UTC 2014 2 hours'
```

However, the above would convert the specified date to my System's date and add 2 hours, whereas I need to achieve this for a particular target timezone and without having to rely on specifying offsets manually.

Comment: _Is there a quick method to do this in Bash or Python_: Could be, could be not, can't say for sure.  Do you have any other question?

Comment: _How can I do this in Bash or Python_: By writing some code.  Alternatively, if you have a magic wand, it might help.

Comment: @devnull Yes I have searched a bit and haven't been able to figure out a solution. You can do something like `date -d "+2 hours"` in Bash, but that will offcourse convert your current time. The complexity here seems to be that the timestamps are in a file. So one way is to parse the date and then do the addition and subtraction. The reason for posting here is that if somebody has a smarter solution than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the offset approach and specify your target timezone directly.  For example to convert a date to Hong Kong time using GNU `date`:

```
$ TZ='Asia/Hong_Kong' date -d 'Sat Mar 15 01:30:01 UTC 2014'
Sat Mar 15 09:30:01 HKT 2014
```

`TZ` is the time zone variable.  The `-d` option to `date` tells it to read the time from the specified string.

If you don't specify `TZ`, you will get your computer's default time zone:

```
$ date -d 'Sat Mar 15 01:30:01 UTC 2014'
Fri Mar 14 18:30:01 PDT 2014
```

A list of timezones by country is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country).

This approach is not applicable to [Mac OSX (BSD) version of date](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) for which `-d` does something else.

Comment: I see, yeah I think that will work for me as I have the country names. I think that should do the job. Wasn't fully aware of `-d` function. Maybe could've stated my question better.

Comment: This will convert your computer's timezone - don't play around with this because it will have serious impacts across your system. It is not how you should be checking and doing date calculations.

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar Yes.  To me, the big difference is that offsets can change from day to day as, for example, a location enters or leaves daylight saving time.  The `date` command knows all about that and takes care of it for you.  By the way, a list of timezones by country is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country).

Comment: @John1024, thanks for linking the list. Yes I think the point you make about daylight time savings is critical.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid No, that is not true.  As used above, the `TZ` variable is specified just for that one command.  It does not affect your defaults or system time.  Even if you did change it in the shell, it only affects how things are printed in that shell and no other.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, actually works fine for me, I just tried different timezones but doesn't affect my Computer's timezone by using `TZ`

Comment: The `-d` option, according to the manual: _"Set the kernel's value for daylight savings time"_

Comment: @BurhanKhalid What system are you using?

Comment: @John1024 now you understood the point - you should also qualify (especially with utilities like `date`) which version of the utility you are using. GNU date is different than BSD date.

Comment: @John1024 it seems that the TZ variable does not directly convert the time to a TimeZone. I tried the following and get same time for all: `TZ=HongKong date -d 'Thu Mar  6 07:00:05 UTC 2014'`-> `Thu Mar  6 07:00:05 HongKong 2014` and `TZ=Italy date -d 'Thu Mar  6 07:00:05 UTC 2014'`->`Thu Mar  6 07:00:05 Italy 2014`

Comment: @John1024 I've edited your answer, the TZ variable needs to be specified in full such as `TZ='Asia/Hong_Kong'`

Answer (score 1):

For Python

```
In [1]: import datetime
In [2]: utcstring = 'Sat Mar 15 01:30:01 UTC 2014'
In [3]: offsetstring = '2:00'
```

Now parsing the two strings

```
In [4]: utc = datetime.datetime.strptime(utcstring, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
In [5]: offset = datetime.datetime.strptime(offsetstring, '%H:%M')
```

`delta` is computed by `timedelta`. we can add/subtract `datetime` using this `delta`

```
In [6]: delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=offset.hour, minutes=offset.minute)
```

Let's check the result.

```
In [7]: utc + delta
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 15, 3, 30, 1)
```

This can be converted to `string` back as

```
In [9]: datetime.datetime.strftime(utc + delta, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
Out[9]: 'Sat Mar 15 03:30:01 2014'
```

For more detail, see: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html